# Inverse of a multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given an operator $M$: $L^2([0,1])\rightarrow L ^2([0,1])$: 
$$M(f)(x) = x^2f(x) $$

I am trying to show if $(I + M)$ is invertible and what $|| (I+M)^{-1} ||$ is.
I am aware of the theorem which says if $||M|| < 1$ then $I-M$ and hence $I+M$ is invertible and allows computation of $|| (I+M)^{-1} ||$. But here since $||M|| = 1$, I am stuck about how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't simply be $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$

Comment: @tommy1996q can you please elaborate how you came up with that?

Comment: The answer below does it all the way out. However I came up with it simply by taking the algebraic inverse, since there are no convergence problems with it and its continuity is straightforward (using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=I+M$ and $Qf=\dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}}\cdot f(x)$, it is routine to check that $PQf=f$ and $QP f=f$, so $P$ is algebraic invertible.

We also note that
\begin{align*}
\|Qf\|_{L^{2}}^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{2}}|f(x)|^{2}\leq\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx=\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2},
\end{align*}
so $\|Q\|\leq 1$.

Now we let $f(x)=\chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$, then $\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2}=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and that 
\begin{align*}
\|Qf\|_{L^{2}}^{2}=\int_{0}^{1/n}\dfrac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{2}}dx\geq\dfrac{1}{(1+(1/n)^{2})^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}=\dfrac{1}{(1+(1/n)^{2})^{2}}\cdot\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|Q\|\geq\dfrac{1}{1+(1/n)^{2}},
\end{align*}
taking $n\rightarrow\infty$, we get $\|Q\|\geq 1$, we conclude that $\|Q\|=1$.